# .NET MVC - Drop Down List is Showing Objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm relatively new to MVC so excuse my probably stupid question, but I'm trying to get a drop down list to populate based on a view model. I can use the VM to populate a list view without a problem, but I'm running into issues when I try to render a drop down.

I get a list of programs:

```
public IEnumerable<ProgramList> GetAllProgramsList()
{
    // Fetch from the data store
    var fetchedObjects = ds.Programs.OrderBy(nm => nm.Name).AsEnumerable();

    return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProgramList>>(fetchedObjects);

}
```

Map them to ProgramList:

```
public class ProgramList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Pass them that list into the controller and populate the form VM:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var addForm = new SuggestionAddForm();
    addForm.Program = new SelectList(m.GetAllProgramsList(), "Name");

    return View(addForm);
}
```

And then render it in HTML:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SupplierId", Model.Program)
```

Essentially what I'm getting is a list of objects that look like:

```
Suggestions.Controllers.ProgramList
```

in the drop down. I can't get it to render any of the properties such as the ID or the Name field. Where did I go wrong exactly?

Thanks!

Comment: Try @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Program)

Comment: VS marks that as incorrect syntax...

Comment: 'No overloard for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments'

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Program, Model.Program)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var addForm = new SuggestionAddForm();
    addForm.Program = new SelectList(m.GetAllProgramsList(),"Id", "Name");

    return View(addForm);
}
```

You just forget the "Id"

Comment: It happens to all!! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Program, Model.Program)
```

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx